# sumarize multiple columns individually with R

Tags: r, tidyverse

Hey I have a DataFrame that consists of 44 columns. the first column is a name an all other columns are variables that can be yes/TRUE or no/FALSE. Every name can have multiple lines and I want to combine all entries for one name and one variable in on field as in the summarise example below. However, For 43 columns I do not want to do this manually, since I am lazy and since it is more error prone. Any idea how to do this? I also have a list with all the names of the columns I want to combine:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(name = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C"),
             variable_one = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
             variable_two = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE),
             variable_three = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)) |>
  group_by(name) |>
  summarise(
    variable_one = paste(variable_one, collapse = ","),
    variable_two = paste(variable_two, collapse = ","),
    variable_three = paste(variable_three, collapse = ","),
  )
```

Comment: How about: `summarise(across(everything(), ~ paste(.x, collapse = ",")))`. Instead of `everything()` you can use `where(is.numeric)` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `across` + `starts_with` like below

```
df %>%
    summarise(across(starts_with("variable"),toString), .by = name)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  name  variable_one      variable_two        variable_three
  <chr> <chr>             <chr>               <chr>
1 A     TRUE, FALSE, TRUE FALSE, FALSE, FALSE FALSE, TRUE, TRUE
2 B     FALSE             TRUE                FALSE
3 C     FALSE, FALSE      FALSE, TRUE         FALSE, TRUE
```

---

A shorter version by base R is using `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(. ~ name, df, toString)
  name      variable_one        variable_two    variable_three
1    A TRUE, FALSE, TRUE FALSE, FALSE, FALSE FALSE, TRUE, TRUE
2    B             FALSE                TRUE             FALSE
3    C      FALSE, FALSE         FALSE, TRUE       FALSE, TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use your existing code to get the expected results

```r
# custom function
sum_string <- \(x)({
  paste(x, collapse = ",")
})

# use the custom function in the code

df |>
  group_by(name) |>
  summarise(across(starts_with('variable'), ~ sum_string(.)))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  name  variable_one    variable_two      variable_three 
  <chr> <chr>           <chr>             <chr>          
1 A     TRUE,FALSE,TRUE FALSE,FALSE,FALSE FALSE,TRUE,TRUE
2 B     FALSE           TRUE              FALSE          
3 C     FALSE,FALSE     FALSE,TRUE        FALSE,TRUE
```